# How do I preview apps inside Expo Go without a local server?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go

Is there a way to run my Expo app in Expo Go without having a local server running? I've gone through the Expo documentation and created builds and everything, but when I log into the app and tap my project, I get:

> **Something went wrong.**
> No project found at exp://exp.host/@[USER]/[PROJECT]

I want a way for a couple of test users to run the app on their phones without me having to push test versions of the app to app stores. Is that possible at all?

I've gone through the Expo documentation, tried the functionality on Expo Go, and also poked around a lot on the app project on the Expo website. I couldn't find a way to share my app to user's phones without building it and pushing test versions to app stores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tunnels to initialize a server that hosts your code temporarily on Expo servers.

Use the `--tunnel` command flag when using the `expo start` command.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much. Don't know why you or OP got downvotes

Comment: @KevinYoung happy to help! I'm also at sophomore level in HS - message me through my contact form on IJB.au if you wanna get in touch :)